# Default tab for bootstrap + knockout js code

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, knockout.js

I can't understand why the default tab here is parameters, not vehicle. On startup - the parameters is opening, although I explicitly indicate

self.curTab = ko.observable ("vehicle");

You can run it here http://jsfiddle.net/56gh1vpk/3/

```js
function WebmailViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.curTab = ko.observable("vehicle");
  
  self.setCurTab = (curTab) => {
        self.curTab(curTab);
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new WebmailViewModel());
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified mb-3" role="tablist" >
                    <li>
                      <a data-bind="click: setCurTab('vehicle'), css: {active: curTab() == 'vehicle'}" >Vehicle</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a data-bind="click: setCurTab('parameters'), css: {active: curTab() == 'parameters'}">Parameters</a>
                    </li>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" data-bind="css: {active: curTab() == 'vehicle'}">Vehicle data</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" data-bind="css: {active: curTab() == 'parameters'}">Parameters data</div>
  </div>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic Knockout quirk. It's because the click binding needs a function *reference*. When you say: `click: setCurTab('parameters')`, that function is actually executed on runtime. Setting the current tab to 'parameters' as that is the last function call executed.

You can either do this: `click: function () { setCurTab('vehicle') }`, or use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) if you don't like anonymous functions cluttering up your templates: `click: setCurTab.bind($data, 'vehicle')`.

Comment: great! thanks for help!